# ¿como puedo centrar un card en Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Quisiera saber como puedo poner en el centro de toda la pagina este `card`. He buscado información y probado pero la verdad no he podido, soy bastante nuevo en esto así que agradecería mucho de su ayuda.

Por el momento solo se centra de esa forma, he probado con `col align-self-center` que es la manera que recomiendo las cuadriculas de ayuda de la pagina de `Bootstrap`

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="card border-primary" style="max-width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-header">Ingreso de Usuario</div>
            <form>
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">user</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Usuario">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image: imagen]

Comment: te sugiero revisar lo siguiente: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sign-in/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para lograr poner el elemento en el centro de la página, debes agregar algunos estilos a tu página.

Suponiendo que el único elemento visible en tu página es el `card` que mencionas, podrías agregar los siguientes estilos a las etiquetas `html` y `body` de tu página:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Es claro que el propósito de ambos estilos es indicarle al navegador que al renderizar el documento, el elemento `html` ocupará el 100% del tamaño (altura) de la ventana del navegador. También le indica que el elemento `body` ocupará el 100% (altura) del elemento padre (en este caso el elemento padre es `html`). Además, le estamos indicando que ambos elementos tienen margen cero.

Luego, debes aplicar los siguientes estilos al elemento `div.container` y al elemento `div.row`:

```
.container, .row {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Así ambos elementos ocuparan el 100% de la altura de sus elementos padre respectivos.

Ya que usas Bootstrap, puedes usar el [alineamiento vertical](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment) aplicando la clase `align-items-center` al elemento `div.row`:

```
<div class="row justify-content-md-center align-items-center">
```

Por último, como sugerencia, se recomienda que los elementos tipo `column` sean los hijos directos de elementos tipo `row`. Debes cambiar el orden en que declaras tus elementos en tu código. En la [documentación de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#how-it-works) puedes conseguir lo siguiente (traducción propia):

> - Los elementos de fila (*row*) son envoltorios para columnas...
> - En el diseño de cuadrícula, el contenido debe colocarse dentro de elementos de columna, y sólo los elementos de columna pueden ser hijos inmediatos de elementos de fila.

Una forma en que podría quedar tu código es la siguiente:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container, .row {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <div class="card border-primary" style="max-width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-header">Ingreso de Usuario</div>
          <form>
            <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">user</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Usuario">
            </div>
            <div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas.

Answer (score 3):

Amigo en tu código en el container que es el div padre , agrega flexbox y center de flexbox; adicional agrega la altura del container padre (100vh) abajo esta lo que agregue

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="border:1px solid red;height:100vh;">
<div class="row justify-content-md-center ">
        <div class="card border-primary" style="max-width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-header">Ingreso de Usuario</div>
            <form>
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">user</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Usuario">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor seria utilizar dentro del **div** con la clase **row** un **div** con la clase **col** y luego agregarle la clase **align-items-center** al **div** con la clase **row** para indicarle que sus columnas estarán en centradas verticalmente así:

```css
.container {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .row{
  border:1px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
      <div class="card border-primary">
        <div class="card-header">Ingreso de Usuario</div>
        <form>
          <div class="col-auto">
            <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">user</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Usuario">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Nota:** El **div** con la clase **row** tiene que tener un alto predefinido ya que si no lo tiene el **row** se adaptara al contenido y no veras que esta centrando verticalmente, es decir el **row** tiene que tener en tu caso la altura de la pantalla para que veas el efecto.

Answer (score -1):

Yo creo que lo más sencillo es que uses el display flex y sus propiedades:

Aquí he te he creado un snippet donde haciendo uso de las propiedades de flex `align-items` y `justify-content` he conseguido centrar todo el contenido de un elemento (en este caso del `body`) y luego ya con aplicarle el `width` que desees al hijo te pondrá automáticamente márgenes iguales.

También necesitas darle un tamaño a los componentes padre del que quieres centrar. (quizás te falta solo eso en tu código y por eso no te funcionaba bien el `align-self-center`)

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="card">
  </div>
</body>
```